# Pouchdb map reduce query not returning document

Tags: mapreduce, pouchdb

I'm pulling my hair out because of a simple PouchDB map reduce query problem. I would really appreciate it if you can identify the problem in my code.

The problem: the query below does not return any documents in the result, even though I passed in {include_doc: true} and "total_rows" returned is 3.

========== code begin ================================

```
import moment from 'moment';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import MemoryAdapter from 'pouchdb-adapter-memory';
PouchDB.plugin(MemoryAdapter);

var db = new PouchDB("test", { adapter: 'memory' });

async function testMapReduce(){
    var ddoc = {
        _id: '_design/testmsg_index',
        views: {
            by_year: {
                //doc.createdAt - ISO format: "2019-03-02T09:53:44.232Z"
                map: function(doc){    
                    if (doc.type == 'testmsg'){
                        var ymd = doc.createdAt.split('T')[0].split('-');
                        var year = ymd[0];
                        emit(year);
                    }
                }.toString()
            }
        }
    }

    await db.put(ddoc);

    await db.post({type: "testmsg", from: "user1", 
        createdAt: moment("2011-01-01 8:23am", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mma").toISOString()});
    await db.post({type: "testmsg", from: "user2", 
        createdAt: moment("2012-02-04 8:23am", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mma").toISOString()});
    await db.post({type: "testmsg", from: "user3", 
        createdAt: moment("2013-03-02 8:23am", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mma").toISOString()});
    await db.post({type: "testmsg", from: "user4", 
        createdAt: moment("2014-04-04 8:23am", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mma").toISOString()});
    await db.post({type: "testmsg", from: "user5", 
        createdAt: moment("2015-05-08 8:23am", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mma").toISOString()});
    await db.post({type: "testmsg", from: "user6", 
        createdAt: moment("2016-06-11 8:23am", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mma").toISOString()});
    
    var docs = await db.query('testmsg_index/by_year', {
        startkey: 2012,
        endkey:2015,
        limit: 10, 
        include_docs : true
    });
    console.log("query result=", docs);
}

testMapReduce();
```

================= code end ==========================

query result= {total_rows: 3, offset: 0, rows: Array(0)}

Comment: The view *name* is not being specified, e.g. `_design/testmsg_index/_view/my_view` see [/db/_design/design-doc/_view/view-name](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html#db-design-design-doc-view-view-name).

Comment: pouchdb seems to use different view name fornet - see https://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem myself. The problem was caused by a wrong data type emitted in the design document. A correct design document looks like this:

```
var ddoc = {
    _id: '_design/testmsg_index',
    views: {
        by_year: {
            //doc.createdAt - ISO format: "2019-03-02T09:53:44.232Z"
            map: function(doc){    
                if (doc.type == 'testmsg'){
                    var ymd = doc.createdAt.split('T')[0].split('-');
                    var year = parseInt(ymd[0]);
                    emit(year);
                }
            }.toString()
        }
    }
}
```